# Spring rest controller - don't increase session life time

Tags: spring, rest

Is it possible to define Rest method in the Spring controller, which, when ivoked, won't increase session life time?

Edit: thank you for suggestions with excluding JSESSIONID from request. However, I'm still looking for server side approach.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. First find out how your servlet container maintains sessions (cookie, request header, URL parameter, etc.). Then, any request that does not contain the session identifier using the container's chosen mechanism will be put on a new session (avoiding any existing session). Also see the JavaDocs for [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

Comment: You can prevent the browser from sending JSESSIONID to the server for those specific controllers.